# "const" "extern" function ptr of a function declared as "static inline"

Tags: c, lto

I just wanted to ask whether it's a good style in C to use "extern const" function pointers to expose "static inline" functions.

Example:

lib.c:

```
static inline int add(int x, int y) {return x+y;}

const int(*add_func)(int, int) = add;
```

lib.h

```
extern const int(*add_func)(int x, int y);
```

main.c

```
#include "lib.h"
int main()
{
    // do something with the function pointer, for example:
    const int num = add_func(5, 4);
    ...
}
```

Reasons why I am doing this are:

1. I can declare functions as "inline" without the need to put these functions inside a header file and expose their definitions, and LTO should take care of inlining these functions where they are included.
2. I can put the function pointers inside a "const" struct, and treat it as some kind of a namespace.

But I feel this is very messy and might actually add some overhead to the function calls if LTO is not working properly.

So the question is, should I avoid this pattern?

Comment: Typically there is no need to ever have extern variables in C code. Functions may be inlined even when they do not have `inline` specifier (which is not supported in C btw) and are not defined in header files. Putting pointer to function into a struct (which shouldn't be an extern global variable) is a whole different story: it is a common practice to expose an API (used in java, php and COM for example).

Comment: GCC warns me for `extern const int(*add_func)(int x, int y);` that the `const` qualifier is ignored. Maybe you mean `extern int(*const add_func)(int x, int y);`.

Comment: @user7860670 `inline` *is* supported in C. And while compilers *may* inline non-`inline` functions, common compilers only do this on high optimisation levels (e.g. `-O2`). That’s of course fine (`-O2` is a good default for most applications), but the keyword *does* have an effect.

Comment: @Bode Strange, I don't get any warnings from gcc on godbolt CE. I usually typedef function pointers anyway. So this shouldn't be a concern.